# trying to create code for permutation by keeping track of characters used

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, permutation

I'm trying to create a code for permutation using recursion, by keeping track of the characters that have been used already but it seems as my used[] doesn't keep track of the characters I add. Any ideas on how I should fix this?

This is what I have so far

```
letter = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)]  
def permuteAux(N, X, I):
    used = []
    if(I >= len(X)):
        print(X)
    else:        
        for j in range(N):
            if (letter[j] in used):
                permuteAux(N, X, I+1)
            else:
                X[I] = letter[j]
                used.append(letter[j])
                permuteAux(N, X, I+1)
```

Comment: you can check out the official implementation of permutation in the doc here https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: Your code is hard to read and understand, and breaks Python conventions. Don't use uppercase for variable names. Never have an uppercase variable I and a lowercase i. What are N,X,I? Please give them more intuitive (lowercase) names, also give the function a docstring and show us a typical call. N seems to be a (local) variable indexing into the global list `letters`; why not just pass a list of useable letters in, directly, without needing N? Instead of iterating j over `0..(N-1)` then indexing `letter[j]`, just directly do `for c in remaining_letters`

Comment: Similarly `X, I` seem to be overkill: why use an assignment to `X[I]` instead of just a simple `X.append(...)` or even `X + letter[j]`? Why terminate when `if(I >= len(X))` rather than simply when one of your inputs is empty? We shouldn't need I at all. It's hard to guess how the code is supposed to be called without you showing an example (MCVE).

Comment: As to `letter = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'),ord('Z')+1)]`, you can replace all that with `import string` then use `letters = string.ascii_lowercase`

Comment: As to why `used` doesn't retain its value between function calls, that's because it's only a local variable, your function redeclares it with `used = []` on the first line, every time you recurse. If you really need to preserve its value, pass it down as a function argument to subcalls, and initialize it to None in the function header.